# Google Places API Text Search doesn't filter address correctly

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to fetch for pharmacies and looks like it isn't filtering address correctly.
When I search for [Walgreens](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=walgreens&key=API_KEY&region=usa&type=pharmacy), it returns some results from Broadlands, Herndon and some other locations.
If I search for [Walgreens Broadlands](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=walgreens%20broadlands&key=API_KEY&region=usa&type=pharmacy) or [Walgreens Herndon](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=walgreens%20herndon&key=API_KEY&region=usa&type=pharmacy), it returns nothing.
But if I search for [Walgreens Miami](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=walgreens%20miami&key=API_KEY&region=usa&type=pharmacy) or [Walgreens Village](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=walgreens%20village&key=API_KEY&region=usa&type=pharmacy) it returns correctly.

Other strange behaviour is that, sometimes, executing the same request two times returns different results. For that reason, I don't know if you will get the same results using the links I provided.

Google documentations states the following:

> The service is especially useful for making ambiguous address queries in an automated system, and non-address components of the string may match businesses as well as addresses. Examples of ambiguous address queries are incomplete addresses, poorly formatted addresses, or a request that includes non-address components such as business names.

From my understanding, the examples I gave should work just fine.

Am I missing something? What is wrong in these cases?

Comment: Documentation says: `region` — The region code, specified as a ccTLD (country code top-level domain) two-character value.

Comment: Also I get results when searching for `Walgreens Broadlands` if I don't specify the `pharmacy` type. It has several associated types, for example `convenience_store` but not `pharmacy`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug, I would suggest filing an issue in [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789006) for Places API.

The unique workaround I can think about is providing an additional information about the area where you are searching the Walgreens pharmacy. I believe the queries with location bias work better than without it. If I use the coordinate of Broadlands (39.0181644,-77.5202688) and specify radius of 50 km, the Places API text search for Walgreens return results

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=walgreens&location=39.0181644%2C-77.5202688&radius=50000&type=pharmacy&region=US&key=MY_API_KEY`

as shown in the screenshot

[image]

I hope this helps!